# Need output of date with year month also with day

Tags: php

I have an HTML search box with select Month and Year and username but I have added a input type search box for month day like 1,2,3,15,16 etc

Output is coming from month year but I want output to come with day of month also if I select 2019/10/18 I just want if date is selected 18 then search result of only 18 date.

My code is below:

```
$SQLL ="SELECT * FROM orders WHERE aField='".$designer."' AND (orderType='Order' OR orderType='Vector')" ;

$SQLL = $SQLL . " AND  (month(oDate) BETWEEN '".$s_month."' AND '".$s_month."') AND (year(oDate) BETWEEN '".$s_year."' AND '".$s_year."')";
```

Comment: you're code is open to SQL injection and should address imminently

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We expect you to ask a specific question here, not just tell us what you “want”. So explain what your actual problem is with getting this done, please.

Comment: Using BETWEEN with the same value for _both_ sides of the interval makes rather little sense, you might as well go with a direct comparison in this case.